# Which of the following is the strongest oxidizing agent?

Tags: redox

> Which of the following is the strongest oxidizing agent?
>
> A) $\ce{I2}$
>
> B) $\ce{Ag^2+}$
>
> C) $\ce{Cu^2+}$

The answer is apparently B) but I think it has to be A) because it is the only non-metal which actually wants to lose electrons. I just wanted to confirm whether it’s an incorrect solution or my own understanding is wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the electrode potential tables?

Comment: A compound wanting to lose electrons is a reducing, not oxidating agent. BTW, are you aware of any  Ag(II) salt that is used as commonly as I2 or CuSO4 ?

Comment: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Electrochemistry/Redox_Chemistry/Standard_Reduction_Potential